# I keep getting a "Too Many arguments" error on a nested If function

Tags: excel, excel-formula, nested-if

I have an item with 3 sources, if cell `$B$11` is `Blue Chip` or `Consensus` I want to do an `INDEX/MATCH` on the corresponding tab.

So if true `INDEX/MATCH`, if false move on to the next If statement. I keep getting the error `too many arguments` and I'm not sure how to fix it. If I delete the last If statement the formula works as intended.

```
=IF(
    Sheet1!$B$11="Blue Chip",
    INDEX(
        'Mtly Interp BASE'!$B$2:$G$1048576,
        MATCH(
            'Supplemental Rates_Base'!IM$4,
            'Mtly Interp BASE'!$A$2:$A$1048576,
            0
        ),
        MATCH(
            'Supplemental Rates_Base'!$B112,
            'Mtly Interp BASE'!$B$1:$G$1,
            0
        )
    ),
    IF(
        Sheet1!$B$11="Consensus",
        INDEX(
            'Consensus Monthly'!$B$12:$EG$800,
            MATCH(
                'Supplemental Rates_Base'!IM$4,
                'Consensus Monthly'!$A$12:$A$800,
                0
            ),
            MATCH(
                'Supplemental Rates_Base'!$B112,
                'Consensus Monthly'!$B$1:$EG$1,
                0
            )
        ) / 100
    )
),
IF(
    Sheet1!$B$11="Moody Base",
    INDEX(
        'Moody''s Monthly'!$B$12:$CE$800,
        MATCH(
            'Supplemental Rates_Base'!IM$4,
            'Moody''s Monthly'!$A$12:$A$800,
            0
        ),
        MATCH(
            'Supplemental Rates_Base'!$B112,
            'Moody''s Monthly'!$B$1:$CE$1,
            0
        )
    ) / 100
)
)
```

Comment: Usually it helps to format the code...

Comment: you have one too many brackets, remove the last one.  FYI, Excel color codes those brackets to make spotting that issue fairly easy.

Comment: 1. what happens if ` Sheet1!$B$11="Consensus" ` or/and ` Sheet1!$B$11="Moody Base" ` is false? (it was not defined in the code)
2. settle the logic 1st.. then by just bracket tracing (you can use notepad++ for this), the last bracket is a surplus, and the whole structure looks like this `=IF( [line2 to 32] ),IF( [line35 to 49] )` , which I don't think your intended logic. Please share if this troubleshooting method helps..

Comment: @Sorceri I spotted it. I ended the wrong IF statement. It works now.

Comment: @p._phidot_ It def helped. By tracing the brackets I was able to see that I had an extra on on the second IF statement that needed to go on the end. Everything works now!

Comment: may I post that as an answer ?

Comment: @p._phidot_  yes.

Answer (score 0):

Proposed troubleshooting method :

1. what happens if `Sheet1!$B$11="Consensus"` or/and `Sheet1!$B$11="Moody Base"` is false? (it was not defined in the code) [ a logic check step ]
2. Once the logic is settled, then do bracket tracing (you may use notepad++ for this). As far I can read, the last bracket is a surplus, and the whole structure looks like this `=IF( [line2 to 32] ),IF( [line35 to 49] )` , which I don't think is your intended logic.

Glad it helps. ( :

Comment: appreciate if you can give a 'tick' for this answer. ( :